# ConcurrentmodificationException thrown by java code

Tags: exception

I am trying to append a sublist of a list to another. Its throwing me the Concurrent Modification exception in the while loop where I am calling the addAll() to append the perm list elements to outvec. I need to reduce the size of the p list in perm object while and then append a specific fraction of it to outvec. So, this keeps repeatin guntil the number of elements in the list p of perm object is <= 1.This is what my code looks like:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Generate {

    //function to generate the output vector
    ListGenerator gen(ListGenerator perm, double frac, int n) {
        ListGenerator outvec = new ListGenerator();
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            perm.p.add(i, i+1);
        outvec.p = perm.p;
        //System.out.println("p in gen function: " + p);
        randomPerm(perm);
        int x = perm.p.size();
        while( x > 1)
        {
            perm.p = firstFP(frac, perm);
            System.out.println("perm.p after firstFP call " + perm.p);
            outvec.p.addAll(perm.p);
            System.out.println("size of outvec: " + outvec.p.size());
            x = perm.p.size();
        }
        return outvec;
    }

    //function to generate random permutation of numbers
    private  void randomPerm(ListGenerator perm) {
        Collections.shuffle(perm.p);
        //System.out.println("perm in randomPerm function: " + p);
    }


    //function to return first f*|p| number of elements from p
    List<Integer> firstFP(double f, ListGenerator perm) {
        int new_size = (int) (f * perm.p.size());
        return( perm.p.subList(0, new_size));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Generate g = new Generate();
        ListGenerator p = new ListGenerator();
        ListGenerator outvec = new ListGenerator();
        double frac = 0.3;
        int N = 70000;
        outvec = g.gen(p, frac, N);
        System.out.println("outvec: " + outvec.p);
        System.out.println("size of outvec: " + outvec.p.size());
}
}

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListGenerator {
    List<Integer> p = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

The problem is its throwing me a ConcurrentModificationException at outvec.p.addAll(temp); this statement. This is what I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.size(Unknown Source)
    at Generate.gen(Generate.java:17)
    at Generate.main(Generate.java:49)
```

Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

Comment: That code won't compile. Are you sure it's your real code?

Comment: Without seeing the code for `ListGenerator` and `firstFP()`, as well as values for `frac` and `perm`, it will be very hard, if not impossible, for anybody to help.

Comment: The code is meaningles - try to give us something minimal and reprezenting the problem, not same half-guess - half-mess.

Comment: hi all..I did modify my code..can anybody please help?

Comment: Stop downvoting this question people. It was 2 years ago. Grow up.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does not compile and the error is not in this part of the code.

Concurrent exception happens usually happens when you iterates over a list or another structure and you delete or add some elements at the same time in the same list.